# Append a line in a file after an inventory string in ansible?

Tags: ansible

This is my inventory:

```
[servers1]
ubuntu-vm1
ubuntu-vm2
ubuntu-vm3

[servers2]
centos-vm1
centos-vm2
centos-vm3
```

What my playbook does is it checks if the server needs to be rebooted (I got that part figured out so I won't post it here, it's part of a variable `reboot_stat`). Now I want it to add `ansible_hostname` (name of the server in inventory) line in a file on my localhost when the condition is met that server needs to be rebooted.

This is how it looks like now:

```
- name: add to file what server needs a reboot
  lineinfile:
    path: /root/reboot-servers
    line: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
  delegate_to: localhost 
  when: reboot_stat.stat.exists
```

Lets say that the `root/reboot-servers` file looks like this:

```
[servers1]



[servers2]
```

And lets say only ubuntu-vm1 and centos-vm2 need a reboot. What I want is when I run the playbook that it appends the line under its hostname variable so that the file looks like this:

```
[servers1]
ubuntu-vm1



[servers2]
centos-vm2
```

Comment: For me it seems as you want to modify/recreate your inventory. One advice, Don't do it. Try to build your playbook in a way you first check if a server need a reboot. Then run a reboot task on the servers who need a reboot and skip the others.  Also keep in mind that variables are more flexible than groups. Instead of modifying the inventory, you could add host variables as well.

Comment: Thank you for the advice but that's not what I want to do. I would never run a reboot task with ansible. I'm literally doing a list so I can reboot them manually. But I want the list to look nice.

Comment: Okay, than insertafter is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Modified for O.P.'s comment.

Try adding the `insertafter` option in the task to tell `lineinfile` where to put the hostname:

```
- name: add to file what server needs a reboot
  lineinfile:
    path: /root/reboot-servers
    line: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
    # insertafter: "{{ 'servers1' if inventory_host in groups['servers1'] else 'servers2' }}"
    insertafter: "{{ primary_group_tag }}"
  delegate_to: localhost 
  when: reboot_stat.stat.exists
```

Add the following to your inventory file to set the variable for each group:

```
[servers1:vars]
primary_group_tag="[servers1]"

[servers2:vars]
primary_group_tag="[servers2]"
```

Comment: I want to create a variable for hostgroup like {{ ansible_hostname }} will resolve to "ubuntu-vm1" if the task is ran on ubuntu-vm1 so that something like {{ ansible_hostgroup }} will resolve to "servers1" if the task is ran on ubuntu-vm1 wich is in servers1 hostgroup. Imagine that there is servers1 to servers100, this wouldn't be viable then.

Comment: I went with group_names variable but insertafter doesn't work because if there are more servers from the group it will always delete the line added by the server before so I would always get one line (the last inventory_hostname).

Comment: What actually happens is if I have 2 servers from a groupd that needs to be rebooted, I have to run the playbook twice which is weird. When the playbook runs, it says that it changed for the both but only the last server is appended in the file, then if I run again it will add the first server and the one that was there before will be green (ok) and then I will have a complete list.

Comment: Also I tried primary_group_tag but it puts every server under the last group in reboot-servers file. Sometimes it put all the servers, sometimes just one, weird.

Comment: Try running `ansible all -m debug -a 'var=primary_group_tag'` to make sure that's set correctly for each host.